# Cell phone programming languages

Tags: programming-languages, mobile-devices

I'm seeking statistics about programming languages for cell phones. Is there any information about how many cell phones have Java, Android, Symbian, Windows Mobile, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head:

C/C++ - Symbian, Android, iPhone

Java/JavaME - Android, Blackberry, Symbian and Windows Mobile (not sure about 7)

Objective-C - iPhone (15% of market)

Answer (score 0):

Per [Gartner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smartphone) as quoted in wikipedia, as of May 19 2010,

> Symbian continues to dominate the
>   worldwide smartphone market with 44.3
>   percent of market share with RIM in
>   second at 19.4 and Apple’s iPhone OS
>   in third with 15.4. Microsoft moves
>   down to fifth behind Android with 6.8
>   percent of market share.

Of course, this is about phone *operating systems*, not **languages** (you ask about languages but then mostly list operating systems, except for Java which is a language usable on almost all of them except iPhone OS, and mysteriously tag this as "Python"...?!).